# can you loop acf sub field into html tag?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I am trying to loop my sub field 'sub-header' into a `<p>` tag so that I can add styles via a class, at the moment it adds the sub field into an empty p tag and misses my class!

```
<div class="individual-cont <?= $bg && $bg != '#ffffff' ? 'container-bg' : ''?>" style="background-color: <?= $bg ?>">
                <? if($headline = get_sub_field('header')) : ?>
                    <h2 class="individual-cont-title"><?= $headline; ?></h2>
                <? endif; ?>
                <p class="individual-cont-copy"><?= get_sub_field('sub-header'); ?></p>
            </div>
```

Am I doing something crazily wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: Where is your while loop?

Comment: what is actually being output in the HTML

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I get ```<p class="individual-cont-copy"></p><p>This is my text</p>``` It works for the ```<h2>```

Comment: what type of field is `sub-header`? - because you can't nest p tags. is `<p>This is my text</p>` the content of `sub-header`?

Comment: yes  that is the content - It is a WYSIWYG input

Comment: then you should try making you p wrapper, into a div insted.

Comment: and add the styles to the div as if it were a p tag?

Comment: `<div class="individual-cont-copy"` would allow you to have you content in your wrapper